# Call class constructor with parameters

Tags: velocity, confluence

Need help with converting this Java code `UserNameTermQuery query = new UserNameTermQuery("*");` into Velocity.

So far tried

```
#set($query = $content.class.getConstructor('com.atlassian.user.search.query.UserNameTermQuery').newInstance("*"))
```

with no luck. The problem is that I need to run `#set($usernames = $userAccessor.findUsers($query))` within custom macro and `findUsers` doesn't accept a string but requires an Object on the specific class. And [per API](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-user/2.0/apidocs/com/atlassian/user/search/query/UserNameTermQuery.html) the object must be initialized with the one parameter — String.

The corresponding Java code is very simple though but I just can't use it in a custom Confluence macro

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor;
import com.atlassian.user.search.query.UserNameTermQuery;
import com.atlassian.user.search.SearchResult;
import com.atlassian.user.User;

UserNameTermQuery query = new UserNameTermQuery("*");
SearchResult<User> users = userAccessor.findUsers(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getConstructor` method must be called on the proper class with the proper arguments. Right now, you are searching for a constructor in the class of the `$content` object, and not giving the `getConstructor` the classes of the expected parameters.

Try with:

```
#set($queryClass = $content.class.forName('com.atlassian.user.search.query.UserNameTermQuery'))
#set($dummyString = 'foo')
#set($stringClass = $dummyString.class)
#set($queryConstructor = $queryClass.getConstructor($stringClass))
#set($query = $queryConstructor.newInstance('*'))
```

Of course, you'd better try to do all this on the Java side...

Comment: Unforutnately I can't use Java because of several reasons. But this seems to be working in Velocity yet search returns the empty set of users. Will try to explore this option more.